# Cross validation for uneven groups using cv.glmnet

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I am new in bioinformatics and machine learning. I am trying to predict a disease outcome using cv.glmnet to choose the best lambda for the prediction. The problem I have is that outcome groups are uneven (30 samples for outcome 0 and 14 samples for outcome 1). Therefore, in a 10-fold CV (even in a 5-fold), there will be a high probability of having groups with only one outcome.

Does cv.glmnet take into account this difference in numbers (since the outcome vector is specified) and it always randomly pick samples from both groups. If not, what is the best way to perform CV for uneven groups?

Thank you all.

Comment: To reduce the number of folds in cross-validation in cv.glmnet, change the value of nfolds. For example, nfolds=2 will be better than 10 or 5 folds CV with your small samples.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I did. I thought there would be another way to choose an equal/similar number of samples for each outcome in order to increase the folds. It will reduce the number of samples in each group, but that would be OK for a preliminary analysis. If there is no other choice, I will probably do a manual CV. I will split my data by outcome, use 'sample_frac' or 'sample_n' to randomly select samples from each group and 'rbind' the sampled groups. I will repeat this 10 times.

Comment: Alternatively you can make the number of folds higher and accomplish the same thing.  For example, if you use leave-one-out cross-validation, it will guarantee that you have at least 13 samples of outcome 1 in each fold.

Answer (score 2):

`glmnet` does not take this into account when assigning folds of cross-validation.  If it has a fold with too few samples from one class, it will make the model, but it will throw a warning.  In the example below we train a binomial classifier with 98 examples from class `A` and 2 from class `B`, making it impossible for most folds to contain an example of class `B`.

```
cv.glmnet(matrix(rnorm(200),ncol=2), 
          c(rep("A", 97),rep("B",3)), 
          family = "binomial", nfolds = 10)
```

The model is built, but it gives the following warning repeated 11 times

```
In lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha,  ... :
  one multinomial or binomial class has fewer than 8  observations; 
  dangerous ground
```

If you want to protect from this you can manually assign your cross-validation folds using the `foldid` parameter. For example, if we have a set up like you described, we could do the following:

```
# make our example data
x <- matrix(rnorm(88),ncol=2)
y <- c(rep(0, 30), rep(1, 14))
nfold <- 5
# assign folds evenly using the modulus operator
fold0 <- sample.int(sum(y==0)) %% nfold
fold1 <- sample.int(sum(y==1)) %% nfold
foldid <- numeric(length(y))
foldid[y==0] <- fold0
foldid[y==1] <- fold1
foldid <- foldid + 1
# perform cross-validation
cv.glmnet(x, y, foldid = foldid, family = "binomial")
```

One other parameter you may want to consider is the `weights` parameter.  This parameter weights the error metric and can be used to help balance the classifier by increasing the impact of a misclassification on the class with lower representation.  To make the misclassification error balanced for the two classes you would set the weight for each instance equal to 1 - (fraction of total) of its class.

```
# calculate what fraction of the total each class has
fraction <- table(y)/length(y)
# assign 1 - that value to a "weights" vector
weights <- 1 - fraction[as.character(y)]
# make the model
cv.glmnet(x, y, foldid = foldid, family = "binomial", weights = weights)
```

Comment: Got error when run weights: `Error: dims [product 2] do not match the length of object [44]`

Comment: @PeterChen After what function call do you get that error?

Comment: `weights <- 1 - fraction[as.character(y)]`

Comment: @PeterChen I cannot reproduce your problem, the code runs just fine on my machine.  Are you running the code exactly including the `as.character`?  If you don't include the `as.character` it will try to index into the the position of the value of `y`which may be larger than the length of `fraction` which could explain your problem.

Comment: `> table(train$target)/length(train$target)[as.character(train$target)]`
`Error: dims [product 2] do not match the length of object [5822]`

Comment: @PeterChen This really doesn't have anything to do with the answer to this question.  I'd try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14857990/2943311) to see if it helps.  Otherwise make a reproducible example and submit a new question.